# Approximating sums of binomials based on the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I am looking for approximations of the following function:
$$
Y_n(x) := {1\over 2^n}\sum_{i=0}^{x\cdot n} {n\choose i}
$$
where $n\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$  and $x\in\{0,{1\over n},{2\over n},\ldots,1\}$. Note that $x\cdot n$ is always an integer.

I plotted $Y_n(x)$ for four values of $n$ (25,50,75,100):

[image]

It seems very similar to the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution $N[0.5, 0.5/\sqrt{n}]$:

[image]

This makes sense, since by the [Berry-Essen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) (a stronger version of the central limit theorem), the binomial distribution is similar to the normal distribution when $n$ is large.

Is there a way to turn this observation into a quantitative approximation theorem? In particular I am looking for an approximation of the type:

$$ f_n(x) \leq Y_n(x) \leq g_n(x) $$

where $f_n$ and $g_n$ are some functions related to the normal distribution function.

Answer (score 1):

The Berry-Esseen theorem gives bounds, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) or [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/normal_approx_to_binomial/).

In essence, as you have p =1/2, the absolute error between the two distribution values is less than  $C/\sqrt N$ with $C < 0.4748$. (Best value as of the year 2012)

Comment: But my $Y_n(x)$ is not a distribution... it's a function. How do I convert the Barry-Essen theorem, which involves a binomial distribution, to a theorem on a deterministic function?

Comment: The second source I was linking above says it: "A binomial(n, p) random variable X can be thought of as the sum of n Bernoulli random variables $X_i$. Applying the Central Limit Theorem to this sum shows that FX, the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of X, is approximately equal to FY, the CDF of a normal random variable Y with the same mean and variance as X."  The bound is a *global* bound for  all x (in the sense of your function) and n.

Answer (score 0):

*Only a note.*

The question can be considered as a problem of interpolation.

E.g. one can define $\enspace\displaystyle Y_n(x):=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty {\binom{xn+1}{v+1}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^v (-1)^{v-j}{\binom{v}{j}}{\binom{n}{j}}$

which includes your definition *without* $\,x=0\,$ for $\,n<\infty\,$.

You can check for $\,0<x\leq 1\,$ if $\,n\in \{25;50;75;100\}\,$ and compare the results.

Does it help you to find an approximation ?